# How to use WF4 to retrieve page flow logic in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, workflow-foundation-4

I am currently in the design phase of a new project where we have a requirement to be able to configure easily the page flow of a web application (will be MVC5).

We provide the same web solution to many clients. Now each of the clients have different users who access the application we provide and host. This users have to go through a registration process, which can be totally different for each client. Some require the user to be approved before registering, some require payment before registering, some require to upload a certain document before proceeding in the registration process. If we add a new client in the future, we want to be flexible (as much as possible) to allow us to simple configure the client in a DB, without any code change and the registration page flow will work as expected.

I was thinking of using Windows Workflow 4 to achieve this. My rough approach is as follows:

- Host WF within a WCF service
- Send request to WF service to getNextPage (or previous page) of the flow for that cient ID
- The WF service needs to query a DB to get the specific flow for that client (or would they just retrieve the input parameters required?)
- Run the workflow logic and return the next page (or if they have to
  wait for approval etc.)

So my questions are:

1. Is WF4 the best tool for the scenario described above?
2. Can I generate one overall workflow with various conditional logic to suit all needs?
3. Do I simply store the parameters for each client in DB and retrieve them each time the service is called? These will act as inputs into the decisions that need to happen throughout the workflow.
4. Does anyone have any examples of this working in practice? I cant seem to find any proper examples via Google.
5. As an example, how would an approval activity work within the workflow?

Comment: You don't need a sledgehammer to put up a picture.  Yeah, it'll drive a nail, but a 10oz hammer will do as well, and be easier to wield.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the 10oz hammer might be then?

Comment: Handle your own route configuration.  You'd end up writing just about as much code, either way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are endless ways to tackle this problem but none of them is really straight forward. If you (or your client?) decide to go down that road and that MVC/WF4 integration really pays of at the long run my first and only advice is to check how others approach the problem.

[ASP.NET MVC / Windows Workflow Foundation Integration](https://wfmvc.codeplex.com/)

Sorry if I'm not answering your questions directly but some of them are really open to discussion and others (the technical ones :) are answered on the link bellow.

Just some more links:

- [Extending ASP.NET MVC Account Registration with Workflow (WF4)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2012/05/06/extending-asp-net-mvc-account-registration-with-workflow-wf4.aspx)
- [Using Windows Workflow Foundation in ASP.NET MVC 3 - A Toy Example](http://amitrevski.blogspot.pt/2012/07/using-windows-workflow-foundation-in.html)

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at the links you provided

Comment: Actually the design decision is down to our team so if you have any other simpler suggestions of how to approach it then I would be grateful.

Comment: Again, there's no simple solution using WF4. As to any other design the options are endless. Good you've a all team thinking about it :)